# Query Error while reorder table

Tags: mysql, node.js

Getting this error while querying this. I'm trying to reorder a table by id.

I'm thinking the problem might be due to ; sign in the query

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'UPDATE users SET id=(@newid:=@newid+1) ORDER BY
>   id' at line 1

Code:

```
SET @newid=0; 

UPDATE users 
SET id = (@newid:=@newid+1) 
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this.

on node-mysql there's this statment that needs to be set

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries